# Why are 'opcode' field and 'funct' field apart in MIPS?

Tags: mips, cpu-architecture, instruction-set, opcode, instruction-encoding

MIPS ISA has an `R` type instruction, and the `R` instruction has an `opcode` field at its first 6 bits and a `funct` field at its last 6 bits. So why are the ISA designed like this? How about combine them into a 12-bits field?

Comment: why should you combine them into 12-bits?

Comment: Because all instructions must decode starting from a common point. A 12 bit opcode would chew too many bits for other non-R types which use them for other things. (e.g.) the `j` and `jal` instructions use the remaining bits to specify the address (i.e. no funct field). After decoding the opcode, each instruction is free to interpret the remaining 26 bits in _any_ way. immediate insts (e.g. `ori`) use the last 6 as part of the 16 bit immediate operand

Answer (score 3):

[image: MIPS instruction format]

My idea is that the three kinds of instructions share a prefix of 6-bit opcode. And for R and I types, the next 5 bits decide source register. If we combine opcode and funct for R instruction, the instruction format is not so consistent between R and I, which may make processor's design complex.

Comment: I guess you could put `funct` right next to `opcode`, and move the other fields.  But that would require splitting up the immediate for I-type.  RISC-V does split up immediates for some instruction formats, and the RISC-V manual explains some of the design motivations to reduce muxing necessary for decode, and to simplify software sign-extension via arithmetic right shift by putting the top bit of the immediate at the far left of the instruction.  [Why are RISC-V S-B and U-J instruction types encoded in this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58414772)

Answer (score 0):

**How about if combine them in 12-bits filed?**

Since the opcode is the same for some operation in MIPS and if you change the `funct` than you can't differentiate which operation the instruction does, for example consider the following add(R,0,32) `add` has opcode `0` and `funct` `32`
And also consider that and(R,0,36) `and` has also opcode `0` but different `funct` in this case `36` which means it's and `AND` operation.

check the MIPS Reference Sheet.