# Why store instructions have their own format

Tags: riscv

Load and store instructions have the same requirements for encoding: two registers and a 12-bit immediate. However store instructions (sb, sh, sw) have a dedicated format that is called *S-type* whereas load instructions use the *I-type* format which is same as addi instruction.

I don't understand why load and stores don't share the instruction format but stores have a dedicated instruction format only for themselves (**S-type**).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why are RISC-V S-B and U-J instruction types encoded in this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414772/why-are-risc-v-s-b-and-u-j-instruction-types-encoded-in-this-way)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe the two formats are different to simplify decoding. Looking at the formats of I and S instructions, you'll see:

```
I: |    imm[11:0]        |  rs1  |  funct3 | rd       | opcode |
S: |  imm[11:5]  |  rs2  |  rs1  |  funct3 | imm[4:0] | opcode |
```

Load's `rd` is in the same bit positions of the instruction as in all other instructions that need an `rd` (I, R, U and UJ formats all put `rd` in the same place). In contrast, Store instructions don't have a destination register, but rather have an address register and a register whose value we're storing, so the bits needed for `rd` are instead used as part of an immediate encoding.

If you play with implementing RISC-V yourself (in FPGA, Logisim, or however you choose), you'll see how convenient it is that `rd` is always in the same place.

To summarize why S instructions have a unique format: they're the only kind of instructions, in a `load/store` architecture like RISC-V, that do not modify a register's contents. The rest of the instructions *do* modify a register, so need an `rd`.