# Why does RISC-V 'J-immediate' encode imm[11] in inst[20]?

Tags: cpu-architecture, riscv, instruction-set, instruction-encoding

Recently I was learning 'Computer Organization and Design RISC-V' book by David A. Patterson, and was stuck by some questions.
Why RISC-V 'J-immediate' put `imm[11]` in `inst[20]` instead of `inst[24]`?

Is it related with detailed circuit design, if so, Could someone offer reference link or better with more helpful explanation based on the specific circuit design?

I found valuable [resources](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414772/why-are-risc-v-s-b-and-u-j-instruction-types-encoded-in-this-way) answering related questions about (S)B-immediate and also read some references like page 17 in official doc volume 1.

Comment: How would `inst[24]` make any sense as the location for `imm[11]`?  That's in the middle of the `imm[10:1]` field, so it would make it not route the same as I-type instructions.  If anything, `inst[31]` would make sense, and put `imm[20]` into `inst[20]`, where it would be contiguous with the `imm[19:12]` field.  But RISC-V always puts the most-significant bit of any immediate in `inst[31]` to allow a shorter critical path for sign-extension, as explained in quotes from the architects in the Q&A you already linked.  So that's why they swap `imm[20]` and `11`

Comment: Thanks for your comment. 1- After reading the official doc p17 detailedly, the 'maximize overlap' is similar to your 'in the middle of'. (Sorry for asking one newbie question without reading official doc more carefully) 2- Although I am not familiar with hardware (which I will learn more detailedly if learning software with bottlenecks) as what I do with software, I can get some meaning about that the convention will simplify hardware design by generalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A short answer is it has to go somewhere, and the longer answer is that with that overall arrangement, three parts of the J-Type immediate then line up with other instructions formats.

The three parts of the J-Type immediate are:

- `Imm[19:12]`, which lines up with UI-type format `Imm[19:12]` of its larger `Imm[31:12]`
- `Imm[10:1]`, which lines up with the I-Type format `Imm[10:1]` of its larger `Imm[11:0]`
- `Imm[20]`, which lines up with the sign bit for I-, UI-, S-, B- Types

That covers J-Type immediate `Imm[20:12]` and `Imm[10:1]`, so what's left to encode/explain then is:

- `Imm[0]`, however, since all branch addresses must be even it is simply take as zero rather than encoded in the instruction
- `Imm[11]`, goes where it can!

As every other instruction field has a mapping, what's left in the instruction is `Inst[20]`, so that is what `Imm[11]` is mapped to.  Despite being a somewhat odd position choice, it costs the hardware little overhead to move that bit to the right position while also putting a zero in the low bit position.

See also the two related answers here at this question: [Why are RISC-V S-B and U-J instruction types encoded in this way?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58414772/why-are-risc-v-s-b-and-u-j-instruction-types-encoded-in-this-way)

Comment: Thanks.
More detailedly, instruction is at least 16 bits (2 bytes), so 'addresses must be even'.